# Getting a "Parent" Start Date From the Earliest Date in a Range of "Child" Start Dates Based on the Parent WBS Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, project-management, microsoft-excel-2019

## Background

1. I used Formula 1 to automate the assignment of work
   breakdown structure (WBS) numbers (D15). The assignment of WBS
   numbers (1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, etc.) is based on the WBS Level
   selected from a validated list (C15), where 1=1, 2=1.1, 3=1.1.1,
   4=1.1.1.1, etc.
2. I used the Formula 2 to calculate the rollup start date (T15):

*Formula 1*

```
=IF(C15="","",IF(C15>OFFSET(C15,-1,0,1,1),IF(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1)="","1",OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1))&REPT(".1",C15-MAX(OFFSET(C15,-1,0,1,1),1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1))),REPT("1.",C15-1)&IFERROR(VALUE(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1))+1,"1"),IF(C15=1,"",IFERROR(LEFT(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1),".","^",C15-1))),""))&VALUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1),".",REPT(" ",LEN(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1)))),(C15-1)*LEN(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1))+1,LEN(OFFSET(D15,-1,0,1,1)))))+1)))
```

*Formula 2*

```
=MINA(V16:V35)
```

### WBS Numbering Overview

- The rollup start date of any parent number is based on the minimum
  value in a range of subsequent “child” start dates.
- WBS Level 1 (1) rollup start dates are obtained using the MINA
  formula and manually selecting the range of Level 1 “child” start
  dates (Levels 2, 3, 4, etc. [1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, etc.]).
- WBS Level 2 (1.1) rollup start dates are obtained using the MINA
  formula and manually selecting the range of Level 2 “child” start
  dates (Levels 3, 4, etc. [1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, etc.]).
- WBS Level 3 (1.1.1) rollup start dates are obtained using the MINA
  formula and manually selecting the range of Level 3 “child” start
  dates (Levels 4, etc. [1.1.1.1, etc.]).
- The WBS number of D15 is 1, which is the parent of subsequent “child”
  numbers under 1 (1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, etc.). In this case, the
  rollup start date for 1 is the minimum value in the range of its
  children’s start dates (V16:V35).
- The WBS number of D16 is 1.1, which is the parent of any subsequent
  number under 1.1. In this case, there are currently no children under
  C16 (1.1). If there were children, the rollup start date for 1.1
  would be the minimum value in the range of its children’s start
  dates.
- The WBS level of D17 is 1.2, which is the parent of subsequent
  “child” numbers under 1.2 (1.2.1 and 1.2.2). In this case, the rollup
  start date for 1.2 is the minimum value in the range of its
  children’s start dates (V18:19).

#### Visualization

[image: IMG:]

#### Issue

Manually selecting the start dates of children to find the rollup start date of a parent is both inefficient and inelegant. Adding additional WBS items would require changing the range of “child” start dates.

## Question

Based on WBS Number:
How can I use the MINA formula to get a parent rollup start date (the minimum value in a range of “child” start dates) without having to manually select the start date range of its children?

For parent items, how can I display the earliest start date of their children?

For items without children, how can I display their estimated start date until they have children (and the earliest start date of their children is displayed)?

Comment: Interesting problem. How tied are you to the current data structure?

Comment: @flexyourdata I'm flexible with the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Generally, the approach is:

1. identify the parent WBS of each row
2. take the MIN of the rollup start date for each value of Parent WBS

The parent WBS is just the WBS minus the right-most integer and one period. So, to get that, we just remove those two things. The tricky part is knowing how much text to remove and making sure we account for integers that are more than one digit (e.g. 1.2.1.12 or 1.2.123).

To do that, we need to somehow separate the right-most integer from the rest of the WBS. To do *that*, we can first count the number of periods in the WBS. This is just Level-1.

```
=$B2-1
```

Next, we can use SUBSTITUTE to replace the ($B2-1)nth period with another symbol. I have used @.

```
=SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$E2)
```

Since there's now only one @ in the resulting string, it's easy to get all the text after that symbol using RIGHT:

```
=RIGHT($F2,LEN($F2)-FIND("@",$F2,1))
```

Next, we just remove that integer plus the trailing period from the WBS:

```
=IF($E2>0,LEFT($C2,LEN($C2)-LEN($G2)-1),"")
```

This gives us the Parent WBS.

All of the preceding steps can be wrapped into a single formula like this:

```
=IF(($B2-1)>0,LEFT($C2,LEN($C2)-LEN(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1),LEN(SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1))-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1),1)))-1),"")
```

The last step is to just use MINIF to get the minimum Rollup Start Date by Parent WBS:

```
=MINIFS($D$2:$D$23,$I$2:$I$23,$I2)
```

EDIT:

Not 100% sure what you mean by your point about child-less items, but if it's "if the WBS is a parent, display the parent rollup date, otherwise display the estimated date", then you can add this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C2,$I$2:$J$23,2,FALSE),$D2)
```

Basically, if you can find the WBS number on the current row in the Parent WBS column, then return the Parent Rollup Start Date wherever you find the Parent WBS. Otherwise, use the value from column D.

In order for the above VLOOKUP to work, I had to edit the formula that returns Parent WBS so that it returns the value as a number instead of text.

```
=IF(($B2-1)>0,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT($C2,LEN($C2)-LEN(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1),LEN(SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1))-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE($C2,".","@",$B2-1),1)))-1)),"")
```

Comment: For child-less items, is it possible to show their estimated start date until they become parents (and the functionality you presented applies)?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Not 100% sure I understood... but pls see edit to my answer.

Comment: For instance, in the graphic I posted with my question [https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E3jU.png], 1.1 doesn't have any children, but 1.2 has two:1.2.1 and 1.2.2.

Comment: Yep, I got that much. Anyway, I think the EDIT in my answer does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @flexyourdata, but the last formula to obtain the Parent WBS doesn't work for anything beyond a WBS Level 3. Also, since I'm am working with a range of 300 rows, not just 22, does that mean I have to manually select the range for the VLOOKUP formula to work?

Comment: Yes, you will need to adjust all ranges to cover the whole list.

Comment: And you're right... of course it won't work :)  you can't have two periods in a number unless you're in India AFAIK. 

You can remove the NUMBERVALUE function but to be safe, format your WBS column as text so that the parent WBS is in the same format and the vlookup can match the values correctly.